# Divisible by 20

Tags: mathematics

Determine the smallest integer $n > 0$ for which

- the sum of the decimal digits of $n$ is divisible by $20$,
- $n$ is divisible by $20$.

Question inspired by [Divisible by seventeen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/26454/divisible-by-seventeen).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> 3980

because

> The number must end in 0 and the other digits must add up to 20 (at least). Since $9+9<20$, the number must have at least four digits. It cannot begin with 1 since the maximum sum of the digits is $1+9+9 < 20$ and it cannot begin with 2 since $2+9+9=20$ but 2990 is not divisible by 20. Therefore $n > 3000$. Since $3+8+9=20$ is the only possible sum under these constraints (i.e, $n$ begins with 3 ends in 0 and the digit sum is 20), the first number that works is 3980.

Answer (score 6):

It's:

> 3980

Because:

> We must have 00, 20, 40, 60 or 80 as its last two digits to be divisible by 20.
>  For the smallest number we'll want 80 to kick off the digit sum as large as possible.
>  We now need smallest number of digits that sum with 8 to to give 20.
>  That's 2 digits: 6, 6 or 7, 5 or 8, 4 or 9, 3.
>  Of those pairs want the one with the lowest integer to take the thousand's place.
>  That's 9 and 3 so we have 3980.